# Test Explorer is finding tests, but not running them after upgrading to NUnit3TestAdapter v4.3.0

Tags: visual-studio-2019, nunit, nunittestadapter

I'm running Visual Studio Professional 2019 and have many NUnit tests in my project. A few days ago, I updated my NUnitTestAdapter nuget package from 4.2.1 to 4.3.0 and now my Test Explorer does not run any of the tests. It throws no errors and has no problem finding/displaying the tests, but whenever I try to run them, it says:

[image]

```
Test run finished: 0 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in 172.1 ms
```

I can confirm that rolling back to 4.2.1, cleaning, and rebuilding the project fixes the problem so maybe the issue is a bug in the 4.3.0 package, however I wanted to check if anyone else has this problem or if there is any configuration I need to do in Visual Studio to fix this.

Comment: I can confirm it, seems to be a bug in 4.3.0 version. Error messages are displayed in Output - Tests after test run starting: Exception `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`, Exception thrown discovering tests in <assembly with tests path>.dll  Unable to access file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\InternalTrace.10812.log".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/1027) (*.Net Framework (4.8 and lower) would crash due to InternalTracelog files trying to be written to the Program Files directory.*) was fixed in version [4.3.1](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/releases/tag/V4.3.1) of `NUnit3TestAdapter` Nuget package.